# Unable to deploy smart contract to testnet (Ropsten) using Truffle Infura

Tags: deployment, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I'm trying to deploy a simple smart contract to Testnet Ropsten but always fails with the following error:

> Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***
>
> "Migrations" -- Transaction was not mined within 750 seconds, please
> make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might
> still be mined!.

I've searched in many places, and it says to change the gas value, I tried almost every value but still got the same error. Sometimes it says that the gas value is not enough and sometimes it's too much.

This is my code:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
const MNEMONIC = process.env.MNEMONIC;

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*",
    },
    ropsten: {
      provider: function () {
        return new HDWalletProvider(
          MNEMONIC,
          `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}`
        );
      },
      network_id: 3,
      gas: 5500000, // Here I tried from 1000000 to 5500000
    },
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.10",
    },
  },
};
```

Contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

contract HelloWorld {
    function sayHello() public pure returns(string memory){
        return("hello world");
    }
}
```

Migrations:

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};

const HelloWorld = artifacts.require("HelloWorld");
module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(HelloWorld, "hello");
};
```

I have my metamask wallet with 1 ether in red ropstem

Any idea on how to deploy a smart contract in a testnet?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because, you are not speciying address and gasPrice. gasPrice varies depending on network activities. You can get the current gasPrice here : https://ethgas.watch/

```
ropsten: {
      provider: () =>
        new HDWalletProvider({
          mnemonic: {
            phrase: MENMONICS,
          },
          providerOrUrl: `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}`,
          // first address
          addressIndex: 0,
        }),
      network_id: 3,
      gas: 5500000, 
      // this might varies depending on the network activity
      gasPrice: 20000000000, 
      confirmations: 2, // number of blocks to wait between deployment
      timeoutBlocks: 200, // number of blocks before deployment times out
    },
```